# Compressing GPS Points

Tags: algorithm, gps, geospatial

I have a device that records GPS data. A reading is taken every 2-10 seconds. For an activity taking 2 hours there are a lot of GPS points.

Does anyone know of an algorithm for compressing the dataset by removing redundant data points. i.e. If a series of data points are all in a straight line then only the start and end point are required.

Comment: A single location record is 4 floats, or 16 bytes. Every two seconds for two hours is 115kb. For which kind of platform is this significant? Even for a mobile phone it's nothing.

Comment: @Pavel: Depends on how many satellites used (up to 12). NMEA $GPGSA sentence allows up to 12 satellites, plus all the other ancillary data

Comment: My issue is not with storage, but with display. If I want to display the route on a website (via google maps) then I don't want to display 1000's of data points.

Comment: @Pavel : it also depends on the data you neet to use. gps receivers no not only deliver longitude and latitude, but also altitude, maybe speed, bearing, number of satellites, etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check out the [Douglas Peucker Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) which is used to simplify a polygon. i´ve used this successfully to reduce the amount of gps waypoints when trasmitted to clients for displaying purposes.

Comment: Thing to note with that solution is that there's loss of precision. Looks good btw, just not appropriate if each point needs to be recreated.

Comment: @psasik: A kalman filter should fix this. There will be an error distribution, but the more measurements that are taken over time, it will improve the precision

Comment: psasik - thanks for the info - will take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Douglas-Peucker_Algorithm.aspx

Comment: take a look at the implementation of the NetTopologySuite project at http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/ project.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621

Answer (score 1):

There is a research paper on [Compressing GPS Data on Mobile Devices](http://www.springerlink.com/content/e3540p208g266733/).

Additionally, you can look at this CodeProject article on [Writing GPS Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20100502060456/http://www.codeproject.com:80/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications2.aspx). I think the problem you will have is not for straight points, but curved roads. It all depends on how precise you want your path to be.

Comment: Thanks Roboto - this info is interesting  but its not directly what I was looking for. Thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to approximate your path x(t), y(t) with a polynomial approximation of it. Are you looking for something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtcZXlKbDJY ???

Answer (score 1):

You can remove redundant points by performing a very basic simplification based on calculation of slope between subsequent points.

Here is a bit of but not complete C++ code presenting possible algorithm:

```
struct Point
{
   double x;
   double y;
};

double calculate_slope(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
{
    //      dy     y2 - y1
    // m = ---- = ---------
    //      dx     x2 - x1
    return ((p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x));
}

// 1. Read first two points from GPS stream source
Point p0 = ... ;
Point p1 = ... ;

// 2. Accept p0 as it's first point

// 3. Calculate slope
double m0 = calculate_slope(p0, p1);

// 4. next point is now previous
p0 = p1;

// 5. Read another point
p1 = ... ;
double m1 = calculate_slope(p0, p1);

// 6. Eliminate Compare slopes
double const tolerance = 0.1; // choose your tolerance
double const diff = m0 - m1;
bool if (!((diff <= tolerance) && (diff >= -tolerance)))
{
    // 7. Accept p0 and eliminate p1

    m0 = m1;
}

// Repeat steps from 4 to 7 for the rest of points.
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code given above has a couple of issues that might make it unsuitable:

- "same slope" tolerance measures difference in gradient rather than angle, so NNE to NNW is considered a much bigger difference than NE to SE (assuming y axis runs North-South).

  One way of addressing this would be for the tolerance to measure how the dot product of two segments compares with the product of their lengths.  (It might help understanding to remember that dot product of two vectors is the product of their lengths and the cosine of the angle between them.)  However, see next point.
- Considers only slope error rather than position error, so a long ENE segment followed by long ESE segment is just as likely to be compressed to a single segment as a string of short segments alternating between ENE and ESE.

The approach that I was thinking of would be to look at what vector graphics applications do to convert a list of cursor coordinates into a sequence of curves.  E.g. see lib2geom's bezier-utils.cpp.  Note that (i) it's almost entirely position-based rather than direction-based; and (ii) it gives cubic bézier curves as output rather than a polyline, though you could use the same approach to give polyline output if that's preferred (in which case the Newton-Raphson step becomes essentially just a simple dot product).