# What is the simplest algorithm of decomposition of the curve by straight lines?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graph-algorithm

I have an array of points (x, y) on the plane that describe a certain curve.
What is the simplest algorithm of decomposition of the curve by a predetermined number of straight lines?

```
float x[100], y[100]; // points of curve
int lines = 5;        // straight lines
float x_l[lines + 1], y_l[lines + 1]; // required to find 6 points for 5 lines
```

Required optimal decomposition so that the standard deviation of all points of the curve from the straight lines is minimized.

Comment: [Guess and improve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), possibly with human assistance. To improve the initial guess, it helps to understand [inflection points and turning points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point). Also note that a good approximation is only possible if the number of line segments is greater than the number of inflection and turning points.

Comment: "the simplest" and bestest

Comment: Not sure if you mean the Douglas-Peucker algorithm - if so, I did a little animation here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621

Comment: @Mark Setchell  Thank you! Yes, I found also implementation of this algorithm in OpenCV `approxPolyDP()`: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is the simplest...

PEREZ, Juan-Carlos; VIDAL, Enrique. Optimum polygonal approximation of digitized curves. *Pattern recognition letters*, 1994, 15.8: 743-750.

> Given *N* ordered points in the plane and a constant *M < N*, an efficient
>   algorithm is proposed to find *M* points, among those given, which
>   define a polygonal curve that is a globally optimal approximation to
>   the given points. The algorithm accommodates any properly defined
>   error measure and the use of the most popular of these measures is
>   studied in detail to maximize the computational efficiency.
>   Experiments are reported showing the performance and usefulness of the
>   proposed method.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Also I found very simple algorithm, but with epsilon instead of M lines: Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm and its implementation in OpenCV `cv::approxPolyDP()`: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/modules/imgproc/src/approx.cpp#L674